# Every noncollinear $3$ points of $S\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ contains inside of it another point of $S$. Is $S$ is a dense subset of some convex hull?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

> Proposition: Suppose $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ contains at least $3$
> noncollinear points. Suppose further that for *every* noncollinear $3$
> points of $S$, the triangle formed by those $3$ points contains
> *inside* of it - and not on it's boundary - another point of $S$.
>
> Is $S$ a dense subset of some convex hull $H \subset \mathbb{R}^2$?

The converse statment:

$S$ is a dense subset of some convex hull $\implies$ every noncollinear $3$ points of $S$ contains *inside* it's triangle - and not on the boundary - another point of $S$,

is obviously true due to the definition of "dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^2:$ inside every triangle there will be a point of $S.$

$$$$

I think the proposition is true: if not, there exists a neighbourhood $N_x(r)$ (circle) around some point $x \in (\mathbb{R}^2 - S)$ inside the convex hull of $S$ such that (at least) $3$ points of $S$ lie on the circumference of this circle, but no member of $S$ lies *inside* $N_x(r)$, and this would contradict the property in the question. However, I'm not 100% certain this is correct and I'm not sure how to formalise this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every open set has this property.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now, WimC. I think there are other closed sets which also have the property. Maybe the question can be revisited at a later date to make it more interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's false. Take, for example, take two points $u, v \in \Bbb{R}$ with distance $3$ between them, and let
$$S = B(u; 1) \cup B(v; 1),$$
i.e. the union of the two open unit balls with centres $u$ and $v$. The closure is just the union of the closed unit balls:
$$B[u; 1] \cup B[v; 1],$$
which is clearly not convex.

But, $S$ has the desired property. If we take non-colinear $x, y, z \in S$, then two of the points must lie in the same open ball, which means the line segment between them lies in the convex open subset of $S$, which we can perturb slightly to get something in the interior of the triangle $\operatorname{conv}\{x, y, z\}$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by, "perturb slightly to get something in the interior of the triangle $\operatorname{conv}\{x, y, z\}$."

Comment: @AdamRubinson I mean, it should be possible to find a point, not on the line segment between the two points, but *near* the line segment, that lies in the open triangle. If $x$ and $y$ lie in the same unit ball, then $(1/2 - \lambda)x + (1/2 - \lambda)y + 2\lambda z$ will lie in the open triangle, and the open ball (which is contained in $S$) for sufficiently small $\lambda > 0$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to argue that, given two distinct points in one of the circles, the triangle formed by those two points and any third noncollinear point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ contains a point in the circle ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson That's pretty much exactly what I'm arguing; I don't really need $z$ to be in $S$. I'm tired and off to bed, so I didn't think of it in the generality that WimC did, but the idea is much the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, $$S=B[u; 1] \cup B[v; 1],$$ would work just as well as in this answer.